# python for loop if statement issue

Tags: python, for-loop

When we run the following foor loop, it outputs the same pair multiple times (see further below), although keptPairs contains only distinct tuples. Has anyone a quick fix on that?

```
processedPairs = []
bestCorrPairs = []
corrCoefs = []
for pair in keptPairs:
    if pair not in processedPairs:
        processedPairs.append(pair)
        bestCorrCoef = 0
        targetx = pair[0]
        t_y = []
        for p in keptPairs:
            if targetx in p:
                if (p[0]!=targetx): t_y.append(p[0])
                else: t_y.append(p[1])
            else: continue
        for targety in t_y:
            corr = calcCorr(final_t,targetx, targety)
            if (np.abs(corr) > np.abs(bestCorrCoef) and not (corr==0 or corr==1)):
                bestCorrCoef = corr
                bestPair = tuple([targetx, targety])
            else: continue

        bestCorrPairs.append(bestPair)
        corrCoefs.append(bestCorrCoef)
    else: continue

for i in range(0,len(bestCorrPairs)):
    print(bestCorrPairs[i], ': ', corrCoefs[i])
```

out:

```
('9.4', '15.4') :  0.9906385237419475
('9.4', '15.4') :  0.9906385237419475
('9.4', '15.4') :  0.9906385237419475
('9.4', '15.4') :  0.9906385237419475
('9.4', '15.4') :  0.9906385237419475
('9.4', '15.4') :  0.9906385237419475
('9.4', '15.4') :  0.9906385237419475
('3.1', '15.1') :  -0.9815967899407816
('3.1', '15.1') :  -0.9815967899407816
('17.8', '6.2') :  -0.9982604771744984
('6.2', '17.8') :  -0.9982604771744984
('10.c', '7.2') :  -0.8082515774139288
('17.3', '15.1') :  0.9810874111013809
etc.
```

We would like to process each pair only once. Printing the pairs after the first for-loop actually only prints them once, however, the output seems like these pairs have been processed multiple times.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is because you are not reset the two variables that are you appending (bestPair, bestCorrCoef)... try to reset the two variable when you start the for loop or you can do it like this:

```
for targety in t_y:
        corr = calcCorr(final_t,targetx, targety)
        if (np.abs(corr) > np.abs(bestCorrCoef) and not (corr==0 or corr==1)):
            bestCorrCoef = corr
            bestPair = tuple([targetx, targety])

            bestCorrPairs.append(bestPair)
            corrCoefs.append(bestCorrCoef)
        else: continue
```